# A 'for each' PHP loop within an existing Array[]

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to loop an array from a database into an existing array.  The two codes work well alone but I only get an error when trying to combine them.... for example...

The current array (which is a list of spammer databases) look as such...

```
$dnsbl_lookup=array(
"access.redhawk.org",
"all.s5h.net",
"blacklist.woody.ch",   
);
```

While the array I am trying to add is as so...

```
$values = $myOptions['re_i_'];
foreach ($values as $value) {
echo '"'.$value['database'].'",';
}
```

And I end up with the following...

```
$dnsbl_lookup=array(
"access.redhawk.org",
"all.s5h.net",
"blacklist.woody.ch",   

$values = $myOptions['re_i_'];
foreach ($values as $value) {
echo '"'.$value['database'].'",';
}

);
```

Which, of course, only returns an error.  Does anyone know how to do this properly or if it is even possible?

Comment: what is in $myOptions['re_i_']; ?, where you have declared this array ?

Comment: recalling from plugin setting in wordpress where re_i_ is calling in an array of databases from a list ... example ... re_i_database[1], re_i_database[2], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to merge the `$dnsbl_lookup` values with the `database` column values in `$myOptions`, which you can do with [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$dnsbl_lookup = array(
    "access.redhawk.org",
    "all.s5h.net",
    "blacklist.woody.ch"
);
$dnsbl_lookup = array_merge($dnsbl_lookup, array_column($myOptions['re_i_'], 'database'));
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kIACC)

Comment: The "re_i_" array will have 2 keys ("database" and "active") and of course multiple databases resulting in what may look something like this as an array...

[{"database":"z.mailspike.net","active":"on"},{"database":"db.wpbl.info","active":"on"},{"database":"dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net","active":"on"}] 

...however, I want to add the 'databases' from that array as part of the existing array $dnsbl_lookup (which is inside of a function).

Comment: @user2284703 this is what I was thinking: https://3v4l.org/kIACC

Comment: Well, that's exactly how I copied it last time (so i thought) and it didn't work.  NOW it does.  that's the kind of day I'm having.  lol...   Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @user2284703 no worries  - I'm glad you got it sorted. Hope the rest of the day gets better!